# ORA-00917: missing comma when i dont have a missing comma

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting the missing comma error. Can someone help?

```
INSERT INTO HDS_ORDER
   (ORDERRECEIPTTIME,
    ORDERPICKUPTIME,
    DISCOUNTTYPE_ID,
    TAKEOUT/DINEIN,
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    CUSTOMER_ID) 
VALUES (
   '29-JAN-2020 11.01.21.000000 AM',
   '29-JAN-2020 11.01.51.000000 AM',
   NULL,
   'Dinein',
   6,
   1);
```

Comment: is this `TAKEOUT/DINEIN` legal?  try `"TAKEOUT/DINEIN"`. Otherwise look for the issue in the dates. Use `To_Date`

Answer (score 3):

You assert that you having no missing comma, but oracle begs to differ.  My money is on oracle.

It would be easier to see if you actually format your code:

```
INSERT INTO hds_order
            (orderreceipttime,
             orderpickuptime,
             discounttype_id,
             takeout / dinein,
             employee_id,
             customer_id)
VALUES     ('29-JAN-2020 11.01.21.000000 AM',
            '29-JAN-2020 11.01.51.000000 AM',
            NULL,
            'Dinein',
            6,
            1);
```

(Took me less time to format it for you than it took to write this sentence)

So, in your column (not VALUES) list, what is this:

```
 takeout / dinein,
```

It certainly is not a legal column name.  The parser is expecting either a comma or closing parenthesis after 'takeout' but instead finds '/', which is the math operator for 'division'.  So that that point it is totally bamboozeled and 'missing comma'

Comment: If you think 'takeout/dinein' is actually column name, then it would have to be enclosed in double-quotes.  And it is absolutely the worst choice of a column (or field)  name I've seen in my 40 year career in IT.  In oracle, any time you find yourself creating an object_name with double-quotes you need to think again.  And again. And again.  At it's basics, creating names with double quotes over-rides oracle's basic 'case IN-sensitive' name resolution.

Comment: Also, for your columns orderreceipttime and orderpickuptime you are providing _string representations_ of what appears to be a timestamp.  If those columns are defined as TIMESTAMP, then you should be using the explicit TO_TIMESTAMP.  If those columns are defined as DATE, then you should be using the explcit TO_DATE (and dropping the fraction seconds).  And if the data type of those is anything else, you have a serious design failure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use
"TAKEOUT/DINEIN" in your query and it will be fine.

```
INSERT INTO HDS_ORDER
   (ORDERRECEIPTTIME,
    ORDERPICKUPTIME,
    DISCOUNTTYPE_ID,
    "TAKEOUT/DINEIN",
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    CUSTOMER_ID) 
VALUES (
   '29-JAN-2020 11.01.21.000000 AM',
   '29-JAN-2020 11.01.51.000000 AM',
   NULL,
   'Dinein',
   6,
   1);
```

Comment: Using mobile. So, please ignore lack of gormatting.

Comment: @marc_s thanks a lot.